# Oracle Data storage - blocks

Tags: oracle, block, rowid

If a row is migrated (or chained) it's ROWID doesn't change to reflect the new block.Why might it be an advantage to keep the old rowid, even if it point to a block, where the row doesn't reside anymore?

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: If a row moves from one place to another (partitioning scheme or table has row movement enabled the rowid will change)

Comment: **If** a row is migrated it **will** get a new rowid. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure that's right.  Oracle preserves a "forwarding" row in the original rowid to point to the migrated row.  Oracle's documentation is explicit on this point.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Kyte answered this question years ago.

See: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=row-migration

He describes the reasons as two-fold:

- Oracle wants to keep the `rowid` constant in as many cases as possible so that it does not change unexpectedly and break tools that rely on it.
- It is more efficient to occasionally spend an extra I/O to follow the forwarding `rowid` than it is to "update tons of index data" when the migration happens.

Personally, that second reason never made sense to me.  It's not clear why maintaining the index would require more than deleting the original entry (as would happen in a `DELETE` statement) and adding the new entry (as would happen in an `INSERT`) statement.  Yes, it's more work, but if you didn't *query* the data enough to justify the extra work, you wouldn't have an index in the first place.

I do believe the first reason though.  Oracle does seem to try to keep `rowids` immutable when possible.  I don't know whether there is a fundamental reason for that or whether it's just because some of their tools (e.g., Oracle Forms) rely on it.